# TemplateSyntaxError without "with" keyword

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to implement a simple restaurant menu website that shows a list of restaurants and their menu items.

`newMenuItem` is the function that adds a new menu item in a restaurant. `MenuItem` is the table of menu items, `Restaurant` is the table of restaurants, and `restaurantmenu` is the function that just displays the list of menu items in a restaurant.

```
@app.route('/restaurants/<int:restaurant_id>/new', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def newMenuItem(restaurant_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newItem = MenuItem(name = request.form['name'], restaurant_id = restaurant_id)
        session.add(newItem)
        session.commit()
        flash("new menu item created!")
        return redirect(url_for('restaurantmenu', restaurant_id = restaurant_id))
    else:
        return render_template('newmenuitem.html', restaurant_id = restaurant_id)
```

The `restaurantmenu` function is

```
@app.route('/restaurants/<int:restaurant_id>/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def restaurantmenu(restaurant_id):
    restaurant = session.query(Restaurant).filter_by(id=restaurant_id).one()
    items = session.query(MenuItem).filter_by(restaurant_id=restaurant.id)
    return render_template('menu.html', restaurant = restaurant, items = items)
```

The `menu.html` template displays the list of menu items, which is where I try to show the flash message. Its code is

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>{{restaurant.name}}</h1>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            <ul>
            {% for message in messages %}
                <li>{{message}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    <a href='{{url_for('newMenuItem', restaurant_id = restaurant.id)}}'>Create New Item</a>
    {% for i in items %}
    <div>
        <p>{{i.name}}</p>
        <p>{{i.description}}</p>
        <p> {{i.price}} </p>
        <a href='{{url_for('editMenuItem', restaurant_id = restaurant.id, menu_id = i.id)}}'>Edit</a>
        <a href='{{url_for('deleteMenuItem', restaurant_id = restaurant.id, menu_id = i.id)}}'>Delete</a>
        <br>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

I understand that the "with" keyword is used to clean up resources like filestreams, but in this case, if I remove that keyword, I get a TemplateSyntaxError when trying to display the menu items.

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'messages'
```

I don't understand how the "with" keyword is making it all work. Without it, shouldn't the array of flashed messages simply be saved into the `messages` variable, to be accessed by the succeeding `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is Jinja2 template language, not Python; `with` is how you define a variable. There is no direct assignment in the template language.